# GetFileVersionInfoSize And GetFileVersionInfo return nothing

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

GetFileVersionInfoSize is 0 (zero) 
And GetFileVersionInfo return nothing

I am using it Like this:

```
function FileVersion(const FileName: TFileName): String;
var
  VerInfoSize: Cardinal;
  VerValueSize: Cardinal;
  Dummy: Cardinal;
  PVerInfo: Pointer;
  PVerValue: PVSFixedFileInfo;
begin
  Result := '';
  VerInfoSize := GetFileVersionInfoSize(PChar(FileName), Dummy);
  GetMem(PVerInfo, VerInfoSize);
  try
    if GetFileVersionInfo(PChar(FileName), 0, VerInfoSize, PVerInfo) then
      if VerQueryValue(PVerInfo, '\', Pointer(PVerValue), VerValueSize) then
        with PVerValue^ do
          Result := Format('v%d.%d.%d build %d', [
            HiWord(dwFileVersionMS), //Major
            LoWord(dwFileVersionMS), //Minor
            HiWord(dwFileVersionLS), //Release
            LoWord(dwFileVersionLS)]); //Build
  finally
    FreeMem(PVerInfo, VerInfoSize);
  end;
end;
```

Based on the stack reply [Get FileVersion with Build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15697092/48705)

It work in most of the cases.

Thanks

Comment: You're not checking to see if `GetFileVersionInfoSize` returned a useful value (VerInfoSize > 0). You're also not checking the return value of `GetFileVersionInfo`. Add an `else` to that, and see what `GetLastError` tells you.

Comment: Yes I see that. But if the file exist int correct Path, what could let the GetFileVersionInfoSize to return 0 ?

Comment: Again, you need to call `GetLastError()` to find out why it is returning 0. Most likely, the file simply does not have any version info available in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not checking the return value of [`GetFileVersionInfoSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If the file name is invalid or there's no version info available, it will return zero (false), and the documentation says you can find out why using [`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). As you're using Delphi 2007, cross-platform compatibility isn't an issue (at least for now), and you can use `SysErrorMessage(GetLastError)` to get a string description of the reason it failed.

I've written it to return the error message if something fails; in an actual application, you probably won't want to do that, of course.

This works (tested on Delphi 7, Win7 64-bit):

```
function FileVersion(const FileName: TFileName): String;
var
  VerInfoSize: Cardinal;
  VerValueSize: Cardinal;
  Dummy: Cardinal;
  PVerInfo: Pointer;
  PVerValue: PVSFixedFileInfo;
  iLastError: DWord;
begin
  Result := '';
  VerInfoSize := GetFileVersionInfoSize(PChar(FileName), Dummy);
  if VerInfoSize > 0 then
  begin
    GetMem(PVerInfo, VerInfoSize);
    try
      if GetFileVersionInfo(PChar(FileName), 0, VerInfoSize, PVerInfo) then
      begin
        if VerQueryValue(PVerInfo, '\', Pointer(PVerValue), VerValueSize) then
          with PVerValue^ do
            Result := Format('v%d.%d.%d build %d', [
              HiWord(dwFileVersionMS), //Major
              LoWord(dwFileVersionMS), //Minor
              HiWord(dwFileVersionLS), //Release
              LoWord(dwFileVersionLS)]); //Build
      end
      else
      begin
        iLastError := GetLastError;
        Result := Format('GetFileVersionInfo failed: (%d) %s', 
                      [iLastError, SysErrorMessage(iLastError)]);
      end;
    finally
      FreeMem(PVerInfo, VerInfoSize);
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    iLastError := GetLastError;
    Result := Format('GetFileVersionInfo failed: (%d) %s', 
                     [iLastError, SysErrorMessage(iLastError)]);
  end;
end;
```

**Always** test the return value of WinAPI calls. The documentation at MSDN describes the return values and reasons for failure (or tells you that you can get it from GetLastError).

Comment: If you are going to display an error message, it is usually helpful to include the actual error code in the message, eg: `var iLastError: Integer; ... iLastError := GetLastError; Result := Format('GetFileVersionInfoSize failed: (%d) %s', [iLastError, SysErrorMessage(iLastError)]);`

Comment: @Remy: You're right, of course. Edited to implement your suggestion. Thanks.