# Last Build number in OSVERSIONINFOEX

Tags: c++, delphi, winapi, freepascal

I wanted to get the os product version as 6.3.9600.17415
when using OSVERSIONINFOEX i successfully get 6.3.9600

how to get the last build number that is 17415

Comment: Where did you find the complete version number? I suppose 6300 is the build number of Windows?

Comment: Are aware that GetVersionEx is strongly deprecated and returns the wrong information unless you manifest support for the executing OS version?

Comment: so which function to use instead of GetVersionEx, if it is depreciated. My product is intended for Windows 8 and above.

Comment: You can use [`RtlGetVersion()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561910.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need the exact build number, use GetFileVersionInfo on kernel32.dll. This post explains using GetFileVersionInfo:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17286050/2501336

This is a documented means of getting the true OS build number and is immune from virtualization:

[Getting the System Version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724429.aspx)

> To obtain the full version number for the operating system, call the `GetFileVersionInfo` function on one of the system DLLs, such as `Kernel32.dll`, then call `VerQueryValue` to obtain the `\\StringFileInfo\\<lang><codepage>\\ProductVersion` subblock of the file version information.

Comment: How do you propose to reliably get the **OS** version number from a random executable image's **file** version?

Comment: I don't propose getting the OS version from a random executable.  I suggest getting it from kernel32.dll. That is a system DLL and this is an officially documented way to get the OS build number: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724429(v=vs.85).aspx (edited my answer to include this information)

Comment: This is just one of several ways to get the "true" OS version without worrying about manifest virtualization.  Other solutions that are not subject to manifestation include [`RtlGetVersion()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561910.aspx), [`NetServerGetInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370624.aspx), and [`NetWkstaGetInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370663.aspx).